# How to replace values in array with zeros?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have array with nested list in it:

```
A = np.array([[45.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 18.]])
```

I want to replace all values in last list [ 0.,  0., 18.] with zeros as a new value A_1:

```
A_1 = np.array([[45.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 0.]])
```

How could i do that?

Comment: (1) If this is related to numpy add the appropriate tag. (2) Show what you tried yourself as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[45.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 18.]])

A_1 = A.copy()
A_1[-1]=0
```

Output

```
array([[45.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to copy `A`. I can think in three ways:

1. `A_1 = A[:]`
2. `A_1 = A.copy()`
3. `A_1 = np.copy(A)`

Then you have to replace the last array:

```
A_1[-1] = 0
```

Another approach can be using [`numpy.copyto`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html#numpy.copyto). In that case you have to initialize `A_1` as a full of 0s `numpy.ndarray` then copy the part you want to:

```
A_1 = np.zeros(A.shape)
np.copyto(A_1[:2], A[:2])
```

Or equivalently

```
np.copyto(A_1[:-1], A[:-1])
```